# Как достать из базы данных SQLite3 определённое значение по ID в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть БД SQLite3 в Python со столбцами `name` и `id`. В столбце `id` находиться индивидуальный номер. Как мне по этому номеру выводить данные со столбца `name`?

Comment: далеко вы продвинулись? в чем  возникла проблема?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то сам столкнулся с этой проблемой. Думаю, код ниже должен Вам помочь.

```py
def getName(conn, userID: int):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM userList WHERE userID = ?", (userID, ))
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result:
        return result[0]
```